# Does repeating a classname in a CSS rule increase its priority?

Tags: css

Suppose I have a `<div>`:

```
<li class="menu-item"> ... </li>
```

Could somebody tell me if I can use `li.menu-item.menu-item.menu-item { ... }` to make this css rule has a higher priority?

**Update:**

Here is the codes to illustrate this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item dark">Item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-item dark">Item 2</li>
    <li class="menu-item dark menu-item-special">Item 3</li>
    <li class="menu-item dark">Item 4</li>
</ul>

.menu-item.dark {
    background: #333;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.menu-item-special.menu-item-special.menu-item-special {
    background: blue;
}
```

There is also a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wenjiehu/6hycnscy/

You can see that the background colour of "Item 3" is blue.

Comment: Don't downvote or close this question, the OP actually found something really interesting I highlight in my post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't good practice because you have to go to the spec to confirm it, but interestingly enough it will have an effect.

## [Oddly enough repeating a class on a CSS declaration will boost its specificity!](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade)

I didn't believe it, but if you consult the CSS spec, there is nothing that *precludes* repeating a class to increase specificity:

> - count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector, 0 otherwise (= a) (In HTML, values of an element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules. These rules have no selectors, so a=1, b=0, c=0, and d=0.)
> - count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c)
> - count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d)

So in your example:

```
.menu-item.dark {} 
/* a=0 b=0 c=2 d=0 -> specificity = 0,0,2,0 */
li.menu-item-special.menu-item-special.menu-item-special
/* a=0 b=0 c=3 d=0 -> specificity = 0,0,3,1 */
```

So that latter actually wins!

---

To add more context, specificity rules are hierarchical, [so below `#foo` beats your rule, as does `!important`](http://jsfiddle.net/bttybpyg/1/):

```
#foo
/* a=1 b=0 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,1,0,0 */
li.menu-item-special.menu-item-special.menu-item-special
/* a=0 b=0 c=3 d=0 -> specificity = 0,0,3,1 */
```

Note: I've only tested this on Chrome and IE8. Because of its undefined nature some browsers may act differently.

Comment: @AR7 All credit to the asker, I didn't believe it until I checked their code. Then checked the spec and it seems legit. Perhaps some browsers check for repeats but it seems unnecessary and the spec doesn't forbid repeats.

Comment: Do you see it having any practical application?

Comment: Maybe. If the behaviour is consistent across browsers you could make a rule `.really.really.really.really.high.priority`. Honestly, its such a new idea. I'm going to do some experiments and find out what this can do.

Comment: WordPress gutenberg/block editor actually seems to use this feature, intentionally or otherwise, for color and background-color.

Answer (score -2):

No that would not work. If you want to be specific then then add all the container ids, classes, and/or tags to the css selector.

`#parent .wrapping-div ul li.menu-item{ color: red; }`

Comment: Thanks for reply. But that works. I add a jsfiddle for the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Actually it does work! I didn't believe it would, but it does.

Comment: Well I had no idea. I just assumed that wouldn't work because it seems a bit silly.

Comment: "Assuming" is a terrible reason for answering. Answers should be based on fact, not assumptions. IMO, this answer should be deleted.